# Solving composite functions

Tags: functions

$$f(x) = \frac{x-6}{2}$$

$$g(x) = \sqrt{x - 4}$$

solve $(g \circ f)(x)$

I know you are meant to substitute $f$ into $g\;$   but I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Ah, f(x) = (x-6)/2?

Comment: $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=\sqrt{f(x)-4}$. Can you finish?

Comment: @kimiTanaka Yes (x-6)/2

Comment: @mfl I am more confused now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(g\circ f)(x)$ means "Apply $g$ after $f$"

as using the same variable $x$ is confusing for beginners I suggest to

$\color{red}{f(x)=\frac{x-6}{2}}$  and $g(u)=\sqrt{u-4}$

$(g\circ f)(x)=g(\color{red}{f(x)})=g\left(\color{red}{\frac{x-6}{2}}\right)=\sqrt{\color{red}{\frac{x-6}{2}}-4}=\sqrt{\frac{x-14}{2}}$